# How to close ConEmu's Tab without Confirmation?

Tags: conemu

I get a confirmation dialog when I close ConEmu's tab.

Where can I configure that confirmation dialog only appears some process is still running?
I checked `Settings->Features->Tabs`, but I couldn't find a option for it.

Comment: There is "Find" field in the settings dialog! Type "confirm" there.

Comment: I found `Main->Appearance->Close confirmation`, Thanks!

Comment: @Maximus I was adding the "/nocloseconfirm" flag to the task bar target... This is better of course... ConEmu is awesome man.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Settings dialog has `Search` field. Just type `Confirm` there.

[image: ConEmu tab close confirmation]

Comment: There is no longer a window "Confirm", but searching for "confirm" still works.

Comment: You are kidding! It is there!

Comment: You're right, I was using an -older- version ;)

Comment: Heads up: Even when "Confirm tab closing" is unchecked you are still asked to confirm if "When running process was detected" is enabled

Comment: Yes, and this is correct. Don't you like to lose your work?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share my settings that helped stop those "Confirm closing console" warning messages when I run Git-bash.

[image]